# An scala collection container with next and previous methods

Tags: scala

I am looking for a class in scala collections which allows me to traverse to next and previous element of a list of items.

For example:

```
val container = SomeClassFromScala(Int,Double,classOf[String],7)

container.getPreviousItem(Double) => Option[Int]
container.getNextItem(7) => None
```

Is there any class in Scala collections with this api and constant time for getNext/getPrevious.

I can write the code but I wanted to see if there is anything I can use right away.

Comment: What you are showing in your example is not simply a bidirectional traversal but also a way to find arbitrary objects in the collection and eventually find previous/next element. How should this collection behave if there are two `Double` objects for instance ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an immutable collection with your requirements, you can have a look at `Zipper` in [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/):

> Provides a pointed stream, which is a non-empty zipper-like stream structure that tracks an index (focus)
>   position in a stream. Focus can be moved forward and backwards through the stream, elements can be inserted
>   before or after the focused position, and the focused item can be deleted.

All operations are constant time. Though the constant is larger as one would expect from something that wraps an array (and doesn't allow insertion/deletion of elements), as it involves object creation.

Implementation is basically by having two lists (Streams, whatever), where one holds the previous, reversed elements. Moving is done by swapping over the head element from one list to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`DoubleLinkedList`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList).  It adds a `prev` that gives you a list with the previous item as its head.

```
import collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList
val a = DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4)
val b = a.next.next                 // DoubleLinkedList(3, 4)
val c = b.prev                      // DoubleLinkedList(2, 3, 4)
```

Downsides: It's not constant time, and it's mutable.